# Must call a designated initializer error

Tags: swift, class, methods, swift3, init

```
import UIKit

class RightAnswerButtonClass: UIButton {

    var rightAnswer: Bool


    init() {
        super.init()
        rightAnswer = false

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

I am trying to create a custom class button with the variable "rightanswer" stored as a bool. However, when I try to build, I recieve the error "Must call a designated initializer"

Comment: Just like it says on the tin, this error means that you didn't call your superclass's designated initializer. Look in the documentation to figure out what the designated initializer for `UIButton` ought to be. Hint: it's not `init()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's compile time error where super class designated initialisation not implement.
As subclass of UIButton must implement(override) init(frame:CGRect)("Designated Initialiser for UIButton") like as below,

```
> override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          rightAnswer = true
     }
```